# Wifi slow, temporarily fixed by resetting the connection

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I've got a fresh install of ubuntu on a desktop with this [Gigabyte wifi card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019JH89YI) plugged into it. The default ubuntu driver seems to be working for it, which is good because I couldn't find proprietary Gigabyte linux drivers. However, the speed is tremendously random, and will often shoot down to the ~.2mbps range until I disable and then enable wifi.

I've found a great many answers similar to this but as the range of wifi issues is large, I've been avoiding answers that involve for example removing modules and etc. What can I start investigating to find the root of this issue specific to my machine/build and then solve it?

**Details**

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Memory: 15.6GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4 
Graphics: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 14.1GB
```

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 38:d5:47:14:2a:9b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:123 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 44:85:00:7a:b4:94
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=10.0.0.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:129 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c03 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a5 (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT: Using an ubuntu forums script, I have output:

```
Booted last: 20 Dec 2016 00:00 PST -0800

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000


##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7


##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,nouveau,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp5s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.37  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5c72:ba8d:7aad:c70b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27624 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:28624912 (28.6 MB)  TX bytes:4181896 (4.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"Speedy Remember Harambe"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.765 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=585.1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:57   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp5s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp5s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp5s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       774     1  0 11:12 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 8260
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-53-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               16.242414.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp5s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:05:00.0/net/wlp5s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp5s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Speedy Remember Harambe
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       3f8fe005-bc76-4f14-a20a-4b9ff06d353f
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     585 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   3f8fe005-bc76-4f14-a20a-4b9ff06d353f | Speedy Remember Harambe
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1482349114
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 10.0.0.37
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 10.0.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 10.0.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 10.0.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 10.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 10.0.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5c72:ba8d:7aad:c70b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 


##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Speedy Remember Harambe]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Speedy Remember Harambe | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp5s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Speedy Remember Harambe
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

wlp5s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.765 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      5   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.765 GHz

wlp5s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>
                    Channel:153
                    Frequency:5.765 GHz
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Speedy Remember Harambe"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000003ede57a2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'Remember Harambe' [AC8]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Remember Harambe"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000003e2e6761
                    Extra: Last beacon: 340ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 


##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     60ED6558F1225672289299A
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     F1176862D12ECD05A1066CF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     F854699497C0353E851B722
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     FD4B9DA2F385F0531B5CB0B
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-53-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    2.244747] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.245702] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.617072] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[    2.617179] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[    2.839204] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[    2.863868] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[    2.878500] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[    2.878580] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[    3.281099] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready
[    6.199988] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>
[    6.208739] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    6.218401] wlp5s0: authenticated
[    6.219758] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[    6.249831] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[    6.251336] wlp5s0: associated
[    6.251370] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
[  501.655804] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  629.431483] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>
[  629.438528] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  629.444300] wlp5s0: authenticated
[  629.444976] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  629.475428] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  629.476336] wlp5s0: associated
[  629.476394] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
[ 1467.319888] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1470.906112] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1471.129828] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1474.344826] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>
[ 1474.351913] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1474.361499] wlp5s0: authenticated
[ 1474.365080] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1474.391911] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1474.393623] wlp5s0: associated
[ 1474.393687] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
[ 1575.034920] wlp5s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1578.590948] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[ 1578.815693] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp5s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 1581.880495] wlp5s0: authenticate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]>
[ 1581.887558] wlp5s0: send auth to <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1581.897142] wlp5s0: authenticated
[ 1581.897520] wlp5s0: associate with <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1581.928003] wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Speedy Remember Harambe' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1581.929503] wlp5s0: associated
[ 1581.929530] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp5s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Can you include `ping 8.8.8.8` trace during one of these slowdowns?

Comment: Weird, speed tests through tools such as speedtest.net are reflecting the horrible net speeds (as well as for example streaming and etc, drops in which are why I notice), but ping doesn't: `--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 52 received, 0% packet loss, time 51074ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.107/25.465/27.550/0.935 ms
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

I notice that your SSID is named, "Speedy Remember Harambe". I recently worked on a case where connectivity was greatly improved by, remarkably, removing spaces in the name. I suggest that you try renaming the network to something like SpeedyRememberHarambe.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Reboot the computer and let us hear your report.

Comment: I am not the OP, but this miraculously gave me a huge boost in speeds on a 4.9 kernel with an iwlwifi driver.