# Unstable wifi on Ubuntu 20.04 Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, atheros

After restarting the laptop, the wi-fi remains at the level of 50-60 Mbps, but after a while it starts to fall to 10 Mbps, then it is in a constant interval from 3-30 Mbps (the reason for such instability is not clear). At the same time, for example, loading a page can take a long time, but watching a video on YouTube (without rewinding) in 1080 can be done without problems (while maintaining quality).

This problem is seen only under Linux. There were no problems in Windows.

```
 - lspci
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

```
 - lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

After reboot speed.

```
watch iwconfig
```

[image: Wifi speed after reboot]

After some time. It may seem that the Internet speed is normal, but at the beginning of the test the speed was 2-3 Mbps, then it began to grow to 50 and at the end it was 60. This can be seen on the chart.

[image]

Next test.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Bit of a long shot but could it be a heat related issue? Upon a (cold) reboot the laptop may be cooler and then as time progresses, the laptop gets hotter and the Wi-Fi performance drops. I have this issue with an old MacBook Pro, in a very hot (no air-con) room. Additional fans help solve my issue, although not totally fix it. Is the machine dual boot? That is to say, does the Wi-Fi perform better under Windows or some other OS? Is this an Ubuntu (and Ubuntu drivers) specific issue?

Comment: There were no such problems under Windows. There was definitely no overheating (the sensors show the temperature in the range of 60-70 degrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I came to the only method that helped me -> [Wifi slow, temporarily fixed by resetting the connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862785/wifi-slow-temporarily-fixed-by-resetting-the-connection).

I will leave the answer here, as I will supplement it if I encounter same problems in future.

1. Set channel width on the router to 20 mhz in the 2.4GHz.
2. Choose a specific channel, not automatic on the router(i choise 11).
3. Set your regulatory domain if it not done yet.

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you see 00, then find your ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2, for example i will use UA - Ukraine, and you use your country code.

Next use that command

```
sudo iw reg set UA
```

Next set it permanently

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

You will see something like REGDOMAIN=. Set it to your country code.

```
REGDOMAIN=UA
```

If you want to check the stability of your internet connection, then use the following command. and pay attention to the parameter

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

This is how I tested the changes. Before these changes, the time difference was huge, after - no.

After all this, the wifi works almost perfectly. Since it worked perfectly on all other devices before these changes, I believe that the problem was in my software on ubuntu, so I will leave this question and answer here.

Comment: still unstable for me, did not solve

Answer (score -2):

It's a driver issue. It looks like easiest way to fix it is to replace the Wi-Fi module from Qualcomm with one from Realtek or some other vendor.

Comment: Changing a Wi-Fi module on a laptop is no trivial matter. The module may not be available for that particular model.