# Wifi issues on "Killer WiFi 6E AX1675 (2x2)" Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using an MSI e16 summit flip laptop (A11UCT) with a "Killer WiFi 6E AX1675 (2x2)" adapter. The problem I am having is that the wifi will work fine for a few minutes getting full speeds of 150 Mbps and then will slow down drastically to 1 Mbps and eventually just stop working all together. This can be fixed by just turning the wifi on and off but will eventually stop working.

I have tried the solution listed here but did not find any relief:
[Wifi slow, temporarily fixed by resetting the connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862785/wifi-slow-temporarily-fixed-by-resetting-the-connection)

networking log: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CPFcmyh7DW/

Comment: @guiverc Sorry that's my bad. I was reading about Jammy and confused it. I'm actually on 21.10 and have fixed the title.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator I included the logs using instructions from the question you linked

Comment: Your WiFi MTU is 1500. It should be 1492. See longer Answer